# What is the reason that the two adjectives are placed in a row?

Tags: adjectives, participles

> "Barking," said Uncle Vernon, "**howling mad**, the lot of them.”
>
> (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

‘Howling’ and ‘mad’, all two are adjectives in dictionaries. What is the reason that the two adjectives are placed in a row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually three in a row: "Barking, howling mad".

The two participles act as adverbs modifying *mad*, and form a little 'climax' (ladder) figure of speech. They're not just *mad*, they're *barking mad*, indeed *howling mad*.

This construction, in which an adjective qualifies another adjective, is colloquial, and it's not rare. For instance, you might see:

> He's scary. Random violent scary.

But *mad* seems particularly to attract present participles:

- raving mad
- dancing mad
- gibbering mad
- stark staring mad

Perhaps this is because these participles signify behaviours, and madness is most strikingly evident in mad behaviour.

Comment: I’ve heard, in an Korean website, one adjective intensifies another as in the case of ‘it’s freezing cold,’ yet your name gives me the authority, putting down StoneyB in the upper blank of the book, in page 99. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In this case that's an idiom and the reasons are more or less historical/traditional, obscure origins of idioms are not really to be discussed on ELL site.

But otherwise, you can string two different adjectives that both describe given noun, or you can get one adjective modify the other.

The first case is simple:

> He wore a simple black hat.

In this case "simple" and "black" both describe two independent features of the hat. They appear independently, don't affect each other.

The latter is trickier.

> He wore a deep crimson cloak.

"deep cloak" wouldn't make much sense. "deep" describes the variety of color: intense, saturated.